# Which animation method to use in blender for later use in Unity?

Tags: animation, unity

I'm trying to understand which animations on blender will be able to be animated in unity.

I have tried animating a net in such a way that when the ball hits it I will activate the animation to look realistic- I built a net, added a lattice modifier and animated with this lattice, but then I saw the posts about Unity not able to run them.

So figured I'll try Cloth animations but then I saw posts says Unity wont accept those animations also.

So, beside manually moving each individual vertex on my net, how can I animate that?

Answer (score 2):

Unity supports [rigged](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Rigging) models.

You would need to learn how to parent armatures to your model and adding keyframes. There're many tutorials on this.

- [Tutorials](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Tutorials/Resources/External_links)
- [Unity tutorial: Using Blender and Rigify](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BlenderAndRigify.html)

Comment: As a site note: There also seems to be a way to use shapekeys aka blendshapes in unity [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyDI8QLZrxA](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iyDI8QLZrxA). Though, there were some [issues](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-blend-shapes-can-manage-blender-shape-keys.210828/) with it. Unfortunately the official [FBX exporter](http://code.blender.org/index.php/2014/06/supporting-game-developers-with-blender-2-71/) also doesn't support shapekeys right now. Might worth to try the way described in the video.